# How to deal with a NullPointerException when outputing an array of objects as strings?

Tags: java

When I try to output the strings from the modules

```
public class Module
{
public String moduleName;
 //public String moduleResults;

 public void setModuleName(String aModuleName)
 {
    moduleName = aModuleName;
 }
 public String getModuleName()
 {
    return moduleName;   
 }
}
```

using

```
public void displayModules()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < moduleArray.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(moduleArray[i].getModuleName());  
    }        
 }
```

I get a NPE when the array(of length 4) is not full and when it is full nothing is outputted when I use the method. I'm using blueJ if that makes a difference.

Comment: Just add if condition for testing if `moduleArray[i].getModuleName()` is `NULL` before passing it to `println` or you can use `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Catching a null pointer exception is almost never the right solution. You need to check for null. In this case `moduleArray[i]` is the most likely candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NPE comes from trying to call `getModuleName` on a null reference.

```
System.out.println((moduleArray[i]!=null)?moduleArray[i].getModuleName():"null");
```

As to why nothing gets printed when you do have valid elements, I suppose you might not be setting the names correctly, elsewhere.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If moduleName were null it wouldn't throw an NPE it would print 'null' in the OP's example. So the problem is clearly not moduleArray[i].moduleName == null it's the Module reference @ moduleArray[i] being a null reference when accessed.

Answer (score 1):

check if `moduleArray[i].getModuleName()` is not null using `if(moduleArray[i].getModuleName() != null) {then print it}`

Comment: I've put the if statement in but now there is a NPE on the if line? And it did output the names when I had 4 elements the terminal window was just hiding on my other monitor lol.

Comment: The test needs to be `if(moduleArray[i] != null)` to be sure you can call `getMOduleName()`.

Comment: @Pritom It outputs the module name but i get an NPE on the line if(moduleArray[i].getModuleName() != null)

Comment: check that `moduleArray[i]` is a object of `Module` class. write `try { Moduel module = (Module)moduleArray[i]; } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("NOT A MODULE OBJECT"); }

Comment: You better check for `moduleArray[i]!= null`.

Comment: `moduleArray[i]` is either `null` or a valid `Module`. You can test for `null` using `moduleArray[i]!=null` (you could also use `moduleArray[i] instanceof Module`, because `instanceof` returns `false` for null objects).